# Xamarin iOS, UITableView, Scroll to load more

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

Can you please share code snippets or direct me to the xamarin docs, how to implement UITableView, scroll to load more functionality.

How to detect if the tableview has scrolled to the bottom?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside the TableViewSource class override this method

```
public override void WillDisplay (UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath     indexPath)
    {

        if (indexPath.Row == tableItems.Count - 1) {
            //Reload your data here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

constructor TableViewSource class

```
isScrolling = false;
```

inside the TableViewSource class override this method

```
public override void Scrolled (UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        // load more bottom
        float height = scrollView.Frame.Size.Height;
        float distanceFromBottom = scrollView.ContentSize.Height - scrollView.ContentOffset.Y;
        if(distanceFromBottom < height && isScrolling == false) 
        {
            // reload data here
        }
    }
```